# How to handle bounced emails?

Tags: .net, email

The users of my app can send emails to a set of people. Some of the emails might be invalid.
I need to let the user know which emails bounced.

Is this possible to do? If yes, any pointers will be helpful.

I use .NET, C# to send email. I don't use any third part tools to send mails.

Thanks

Comment: There is no reliable means of determining if an email was delivered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this a couple of years ago using http://mailsystem.codeplex.com/.  It is open source now but it cost me money back then.

You will receive a message back indicating a bounce and there are properties in the code that gives you the original sender so you can deliver it properly.

Comment: Of course I didn't mention that I had exchange forward certain email to an smtp folder of which I was monitoring.

Comment: can it handle if there are multiple senders and same email can be used by any sender

Comment: Sure it can.  The application I developed handled more than 50,000 messages each day.  The mail was in all different formats with attachments too.  And that code (which you can use) was the mail component.  It is pretty robust.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [MailBounceDetector](https://github.com/rgl/MailBounceDetector) repository.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

A "bounce" generally goes back to the sender of the email, not your application.  It's not really designed to be handled by an application in the way you suggest.  The user(s) should receive notification of the bounce from the email server(s) in question (assuming all goes well, as OMG Ponies said there's really no reliable way).

In order for your application to be the recipient of the bounce and respond to it in any meaningful way, a lot of work would have to be done on your part.  Your application would basically have to be the mail server for the user account on behalf of which it sends the emails.  It'll have to listen on port 25 and parse incoming messages for bounces.

This is no trivial task.  Just "being a mail server" works fine in theory, except that most other mail servers in the world are going to ignore you unless you're a proper domain with proper MX records and all that.  Also, if you're listening for incoming stuff on port 25, expect a lot of noise.

It's best to let the users receive the bounces properly by having the mail be sent on their behalf in the first place.

Comment: I need the easy and quick solution. This is most important requirement. Currently I set the from email address to be 'noreply@company.com'. So if I set the sender's email as the from address, then bounced emails will go to user not my app, right?

Comment: You don't have to use port 25.  You can have a mail server forward to a folder for you.  You don't have to be the end point and no mx records are modified.   They almost all have this feature.

Comment: @phillip: That's true enough, I didn't think of that.  @Projapati: That's probably your best bet.  Have the company's mail server store messages for 'noreply@company.com' to drop into a folder.  Then your application can make use of a `FileSystemWatcher` to monitor this folder and parse the incoming messages.  Based on their content you'll have to match them up with the appropriate user and use whatever notification system your application may already have to let that user know.